# How to get current date in next month

Tags: php

I've done some research over internet and i cannot find the right answer that closes to  my problem. I'm just beginner in php and I don't understand advance programming yet. My problem is I want to get the current date in next month.

suppose:
today is Feb 15 2014,

I want to get date

**March 15 2014**,

**April 15 2014**,

**May 15 2014**,

**June 15 2014**,

**July 15 2014**,

**August 15 2014**,

**September 15 2014**,

**October 15 2014**,

**November 15 2014**,

**December 15 2014**,

**January 15 2015**, and so on and so fourth.

Comment: what is "current date of next month" in the example "January 31 2016"?

Comment: hi @PeterMiehle good question! Feb 28 2016.

Comment: Hi @PeterMiehle do you have alternate solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$new_date = date('F d Y', strtotime('+1 month'));
```

or

```
for ($i = 1; $i <12; $i++){

  $new_date = date('F d Y', strtotime("+$i month"));
  echo $new_date;
}
```

Comment: This won't work on case like January 31 2016. "+1 month" for example will always add 31 days in this case. So you will get March 3 2016 in this case. OP wants February 28 2016 as mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2014-03-15' );
$end = new DateTime( '2015-01-31' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("F d Y") . "<br>";
}
```

or this if you want to do it without a end date:

```
$date= new DateTime( '2014-03-15' );

for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $date = $date->modify( '+1 month' ); 
    echo $date->format("F d Y") . "<br>";
}
```